# An integral formula on a Riemannian manifold

Tags: integration, geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, laplacian

I'm reading Kobayashi's book transformations group in differential geometry and at the page 156 is this integral formula:

> [image]

My question is how I can write a proof that is invariant i.e. index free? I'm having a hard time identifying those objects in the first formula.

Edit: the missing formula for laplacian is this one

> [image]

Comment: The missing piece is the formula for the Laplacian ("see Appendix 3").  Can you provide it?  Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I've made an edit

Comment: Thanks a lot; very helpful.

Comment: My problem is not the calculation but the notation with a lot of indexes...

Comment: No, that's the formula for the Laplacian of a differential form, not of a vector field.

Comment: The Laplacian of a 1-form it is a 1-form. If $\alpha$ is the dual form of $X$ then $\Delta X$ is just the dual vector field of $\Delta \alpha$

Comment: So, I kinda see that $\sum R_{ij}\zeta^i\eta^j$ is just the Ricci tensor and the first term is the divergence of a vector field but I don't know whats that field in terms of $X$ and $Y$